# Related Rates - possible textbook error

Tags: calculus, geometry

Recently I've been asked to do some exercises from a textbook but I cannot understand how the author derived the correct answer.

**Here is the exercise in question:**

> At $8$:$00$ boat $A$ is located $25\,km$ south of boat $B$. If boat $A$ is traveling west at $16\,km/h$ and boat $B$ south at $20\,km/h$, at what rate is the distance between the boats changing at $8$:$30$?

**Textbook answer:** $25.6\,km/h$

**My answer:** $-10.12\,km/h$

[image]

I have likely made a mistake somewhere.

Could someone help me determine which answer is correct?

Comment: Your solution is clearly laid out, and correct.

Comment: Do you agree with my result Peter?

Comment: @Peter do you agree with the result also?

Comment: I tried the alternative calculation (calculate the difference and derive at $x=\frac{1}{2}$) and approved your result.

Comment: Does your textbook only give the answer? I would count more on those with fuller explanations and less problems.

Comment: It is actually one of the college teacher's textbook @Kbot

Comment: @bru1987 I assume, as he said "textbook"